# Umbraco CMS 5.0 CTP 1 installation skip some steps and does not populate DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cms

I wish to try Umbraco CMS 5.0 CTP 1 since it has a good reputation.

Since im into ASP MVC 3, I thought I would try to install the preview of V5. I know this might be buggy, but I did expect that I could install it properly, but that was not correct.

I start the installation vizard, go through step 1- 3.

In step 3 I add my DB information (which I know works), and go to the next step.
Then it looks like everything is OK, and I get this message:

> The Umbraco database is being configured. This process populates your chosen database with a blank Umbraco instance. Installation completed!

But when I look in my DB I see no tables, so something did not go as planned. I then click "Continue". And now I arrive at step 5 (step 4 was skipped).

Step 5 says "Install a Starter kit", with a HUGE button with the text "Dev data set". I click this button, and installation is completed.

I now have 2 choices, "Preview your new website" and "Set up your new website". If I click on "Set up your new website" I return to step 1 of the installation vizard.

What might go wrong? I tried looking into the log file, but I did not find anything of interest to me.

Server: Windows 2008
SQL: SQL Server 2008
MVC3 installed, ASP.NET 4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better asking this question in [Umbraco's support forum](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco), especially as this is a beta release and likely to have issues.